# Get autocomplete options by AJAX according to typed value

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I need to use autocomplete (of jQuery UI) in order to suggest usernames from my database as you type.

The regular way is to use autocomplete's `source`, but my website has tons of usernames, and I don't want to have one giant string to keep the usernames.
I was thinking about a better way to do it:

When the user types the first letter(s) of a username, an AJAX post request is called to a PHP file, that gets the usernames that start with the letter.
Then, it returns the list to the jQuery, and then process it and make the result the options for the autocomplete.

**Is this way better than having one big string with all options?** I couldn't code my way myself (couldn't figure out how to turn the mysql result to autocomplete options). **And what's the right way to code this?** Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of what I've done before:

JS

```
$("#username").autocomplete({
    source: "autocomplete.php",   // Source for autocomplete must be an array, echoed out via json
    minLength: 1 // Min length before autocomplete starts searching the array from source
  });
```

PHP

```
// Pull in searchterm from username, $_GET['TERM'] is a built-in variable for autocomplete
$term = strtolower($_GET['term']); 

$searchTerm = "$term%";
$query = "SELECT distinct username from access WHERE username LIKE ? ORDER BY username";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
if($stmt){
  $stmt->bind_param("s",$searchTerm);
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->bind_result($username);
}

// Create array for autocomplete to search
$usernameList = array(); 
while ($stmt->fetch()){
        $usernameList[] = $username;  // Assign names to the list
}
// Echo json data for autocomplete to retrieve   
echo json_encode($usernameList); 
$db->close();
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="username[]" id="username" />
```